# Phone Applications having SSL/TLS enabled behind the scenes?

Tags: encryption, tls, smartphone

**Please Note:** This question is slightly based on me being a tin foiled hat with the issues that has arisen from the leaks, documents, and questioning trust thanks to Edward Snowden.

---

Thanks to adding my VPN service to my cellphone to improve security and stop "eavesdropping" of Verizon on my data and usage, I am questioning the trust with Twitter, Facebook, Google, and all of the major social networking applications and how they are keeping our data secure as we access their applications.

There is no notice, information, or indication that they are using SSL/TLS within their applications for Android, Windows Phone, and iPhones.

Is Facebook, Twitter, Google Plus, and other major applications have SSL/TLS enabled and coded into their phone/tablet applications behind the scenes?

Comment: You are worried about how secure the data is during transmission to the guys who spy on you and track you across the web for profit?? You know that all those platforms aggregate user data for sale to 3rd parties?? 3rd parties meaning anyone with enough money. Including governments and the private security sector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer for your question is **yes**, most major (and official) social networking apps use encrypted connections.
However, if you are interested, there are ways you can find out for yourself by setting up a proxy server that allows you to forward traffic through that system and then analyze the data. There are however, some tools to do this:

**1-** There is an [**Androguard extension**](https://code.google.com/p/androguard/#Description) called **MalloDroid** that

> facilitates static code analysis of Android applications.

Specific details are as follows:

- Analyze the networking API calls, and extract valid HTTP(S) URLs from
  the decompiled apps
- Check the validity of the SSL certificates of all extracted HTTPS
  hosts.
- Identify apps containing API calls that differ from Android's default
  SSL usage, e.g., contain non-default trust managers, SSL socket
  factories or hostname verifiers with permissive verification
  strategies.

**2-** [**ZAP**](http://zap.zscaler.com/search.php) by Zscaler is a

> web-based tool designed to streamline the capture and analysis of
> HTTP(S) traffic from mobile applications. ZAP is capable of analyzing
> traffic from both **iOS and Android** applications.

ZAP checks the following:

- **Authentication:** Username/password sent in clear text or using weak
  encoding methods.
- **Device Metadata Leakage:** Data that can identify an individual device,
  such as the Unique Device Identifier (UDID).
- **Personally Identifiable Information Leakage:** Data that can identify
  an individual user, such as an email address, phone number or mailing
  address.
- **Exposed content:** Communication with third parties such as advertising
  or analytics sites.

*Sources:*

> http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/android-apps-and-ssl-wheres-the-padlock/
>
> http://zap.zscaler.com/about.php
>
> https://code.google.com/p/androguard/#Description

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself this question two years ago, and I decided to see by myself. I set a lab with a MITM attack scenario and tested a couple of applications including Twitter and Whatsapp.

- The answer to your question: **Yes** most of these apps do use encrypted connections to transfer your data from your phone to their servers. Yet, remember once your data reaches them it is up to them to store it in the clear-text or encrypt it and then store it, or simply delete it!
- Another thing to note is the fact that these apps may fall into SSL-MITM attacks where an attacker generates his own certificate and sends it to the app claiming he is the server. Unless the app is programmed to reject such fake certs, anybody can still *sniff* your data EVEN if it is encrypted. (I can confirm that Twitter is not vulnerable to this the day I tested)
- This applies to other operating system apps such as Contacts, iCloud service, Notes, etc..